# Getting current base fee from json rpc

Tags: json-rpc, gas-price, eip-1559, london

I'm looking for a way to fetch current base fee using JSON RPC (and go-ethereum `ethclient.Client` as client)

I'm aware of new JSON RPC `eth_maxPriorityFeePerGas` which gives me second parameter - but this endpoint dosen't anwser the base fee question

Only way to get near the result I expected is `eth_gasPrice` - `eth_maxPriorityFeePerGas`, which gives me good approximation, but numbers don't match with etherscan (block view -> Base Fee Per Gas) and seem to be off by anything between 0.5 to 10 GWEI.

Comment: you can get the base fee from last block and then multiply it using the same formula as in ethereum golang

Comment: @Nulik this sounds like workaround, but okay - that's very good pointer though, I think I can construct anwser out of your pointer.

Comment: ok, the base fee is in the header, and the function to calculate base fee for the next block is here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/62ad17fb0046243255048fbf8cb0882f48d8d850/consensus/misc/eip1559.go#L55

Comment: @Nulik yes, I have working sample code, but Im doing multiple blocks verification if it works as expected before I post self-anwser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON RPC does not contain method that can return this data, unfortunately.

As suggested by @Nulik in comment, it's possible to calculate this precisely from go-ethereum library, using `misc.CalcBaseFee()` function, where config can be gathered from `params.MainnetChainConfig`

While this isn't direct solution (dosen't use JSON RPC), it's only solution that is immidietely available.

Full code example (removed error handling for brievety):

```go
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "math/big"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/consensus/misc"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/params"
)

const ethJSONRPCEndpointAddress = "http://path-to-json-rpc:8545"

func main() {
    config := params.MainnetChainConfig
    ethClient, _ := ethclient.DialContext(context.Background(), ethJSONRPCEndpointAddress)
    bn, _ := ethClient.BlockNumber(context.Background())

    bignumBn := big.NewInt(0).SetUint64(bn)
    blk, _ := ethClient.BlockByNumber(context.Background(), bignumBn)
    baseFee := misc.CalcBaseFee(config, blk.Header())
    fmt.Printf("Base fee for block %d is %s\n", bn+1, baseFee.String())
}
```

example output:

```
Base fee for block 13102540 is 92382639576
```

[Etherscan agrees with this estimation](https://etherscan.io/block/13102540)